# Can UPDATE referencing fields from the updated table cause deadlock?

Tags: mariadb, locking, deadlock

I have a query like this:

`UPDATE loginlogs SET rxbytes = rxbytes + ?, txbytes = txbytes + ? WHERE logid = ?`

from time to time, my DB gets into a deadlock and `SELECT * FROM sys.innodb_lock_waits` shows pending locks like this:

```
wait_started    wait_age        wait_age_secs   locked_table    locked_index    locked_type     waiting_trx_id  waiting_trx_started     waiting_trx_age waiting_trx_rows_locked waiting_trx_rows_modified       waiting_pid     waiting_query   waiting_lock_id waiting_lock_mode       blocking_trx_id blocking_pid    blocking_query  blocking_lock_id        blocking_lock_mode      blocking_trx_started    blocking_trx_age        blocking_trx_rows_locked        blocking_trx_rows_modified      sql_kill_blocking_query sql_kill_blocking_connection
2020-12-27 07:43:32     00:00:04        4       `db`.`loginlogs`   PRIMARY RECORD  37075679818     2020-12-27 07:43:32     00:00:04        1       0       19194139        UPDATE loginlogs SET  ... HERE logid = 64634225227638257       37075679818:921:15944673:61     X       37075617021     19191704        UPDATE loginlogs SET ... HERE logid = 64634225227638257       37075617021:921:15944673:61     X       2020-12-27 07:43:07     00:00:29        1       0       KILL QUERY 19191704     KILL 19191704
```

As you can see, the 2 identical queries seem to run at the same time. And the 2nd one is waiting for the first one to complete.

I thought MySQL should handle simple UPDATE queries like this. Do I need to first select the bytes and then do the UPDATE without referencing `rxbytes` and `txbytes` in the new values?

BTW this started happening after update from MariaDB 10.4.2 to 10.4.17, therefore I also suspect MariaDB bug and I opened a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24494).

Comment: The transaction in which you are doing this UPDATE needs to be as short as possible (if you want to avoid deadlocks). This context is not given here.  Can I assume you are doing this UPDATE in a long transaction ?

Comment: @Luuk the UPDATE is the only query in the transaction. I just have multiple places that call this UPDATE query from different servers. And from time to time, I have a deadlock which in logs shows that one UPDATE is waiting for another UPDATE with same logid to finish (as this original UPDATE holds X lock). No idea how to find what the original UPDATE is waiting for.

Comment: Is it correct for multiple updates to have the same logid ? (It seems strange to have that)

Comment: @Luuk No, logid is PRIMARY key

Comment: So, if there are two statement that have the same logid, then there is an error in getting/determining the logid.  If you are getting the (last) logid, and some time later another process is also getting the (last) logid, they should not (=never) get the SAME logid.

Comment: the loginlogs table has logid as primary key. Every row has a unique logid. But UPDATE statement can be called N times for same logid. The issue occurs when its called 2 times for the same logid, then the row is locked and for some reason the X lock is never removed.

Comment: "But UPDATE statement can be called N times for same logid". You should verify that a process is using only 1 logid, and that this logid is NOT used by any other process.   (But I do not know your application, so i cannot really of much more help, you need to debug more....)

Comment: @Luuk well I cannot do that, I have a concurrency with this query and whole point of using MySQL is that it should handle simple concurrency like this. Its not like I am making some joint updates, its a single UPDATE statement that can be run more times at once with the same logid. And MariaDB should handle this

Answer (score 2):

## A lock-wait is not a deadlock!

I see this misunderstanding frequently.

What you have shown is a lock-wait. That is, one transaction is waiting for the other. Every UPDATE locks the rows it examines, and any concurrent UPDATE has to wait for the first one to COMMIT to release those row locks. That's a lock-wait. It's normal and common.

A deadlock is different. It's where two transactions get into a mutual lock-wait. UPDATE1 locks some rows, but does not commit yet. Then UPDATE2 tries to update the same rows, and begins waiting. Then the transaction for UPDATE1 tries another locking statement, that needs locks on some rows already held by the transaction for UPDATE2, possibly from a previous statement it ran. Thus both transactions are waiting for the other, and won't COMMIT to release the locks they hold, because they're waiting. The deadlock is so named because there's no way to resolve the mutual wait.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html says:

> A deadlock is a situation where different transactions are unable to proceed because each holds a lock that the other needs. Because both transactions are waiting for a resource to become available, neither ever release the locks it holds.

You won't experience a delay from a true deadlock. MySQL watches for these cyclical lock-waits and forces one of them to rollback its transaction. This happens nearly instantly, so there is virtually no waiting.

So why did this start happening to you when you upgraded from MariaDB 10.4.2 to 10.4.17. Apparently something changed that affects either the number of rows locked, or the duration of the transaction, to make it more likely that you have concurrent transactions conflict in this way.

Or else the software did *not* change anything related to locking or transactions, but it was your traffic that changed, coincidentally, as you upgraded to the new version of MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks. It did cause MariaDB to crash and restart eventually tho...

Comment: You didn't mention crashing in your question or in your bug. That's not an effect of either lock-waits or deadlocks. Are you using "crash" to mean "time out"?

Comment: I mean that I get this: `2020-12-27  7:59:00 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.` and DB restarts

Comment: That likely has nothing to do with your transaction. You did nothing wrong. It's an internal bug, like the one described here: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17407. I suggest you follow up with MariaDB support.